# PHP preg_match_all multiple HTML tags

Tags: php, iframe, expression, preg-match-all

I'm looking to use a single regular expression to find 2 multiple kinds of tags. I found in another question regarding this topic that use the `|` to make a `(p|h1|table)` looking syntax, it just didn't seem to work for me.

My original pattern for only finding iframes

`$removeiframe = preg_replace("#<iframe[^>]+>.*?</iframe>#is", "", $descriptiontext);`

The pattern i tried using:

```
$removeiframe = preg_replace("#<(iframe|img)[^>]+>.*?</(iframe|img)>#is", "", $descriptiontext);
```

The response I'm currently getting with the last pattern:

If the text contains a single iframe, that gets returned.

If the text contains multiple iframes, it returns this

```
[
    [0] => '<iframe></iframe>'
    [1] => '<img></img><iframe></iframe>'
]
```

and what i am trying to get

```
[
    [0] => '<iframe></iframe>',
    [1] => '<img></img>',
    [2] => '<iframe></iframe>',
]
```

Comment: regular expressions are not a good way to deal with HTML or XML documents. Use XML parser (DOMDocument) instead

Comment: Use a backreference `(\\1)` instead of the second alternative list.

Comment: Hey @MaximKrizhanovsky I completely forgot to write how i am using this. This is used as a description field, whereas you can paste in an iframe and it will automatically pick it out of the text and place it elsewhere. The entire field is a textarea. Would this still be possible using DOMDocument?

Comment: @mario Your suggestion did not work either, it just ended up not finding anything at all..

Comment: @Kjaal yes, you can load HTML from string and use DOM operations to traverse the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Ungreedy expression for this (add U flag)

Comment: You shouldn't use regex's to consume markup at all, and even so: this is a comment, not an answe

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem It would be better if he gave a coding example, but this definitely is an answer (it may not be the right one, but that's what up/downvotes are for). [See this Meta post for why](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)